# A fibonacci wedding cake

Tags: co.combinatorics

I know some connections between the triangle below and other parts of mathematics, and I'm looking for more. It's a sort of Pascal triangle, but for the Fibonacci numbers.
$$
\begin{matrix}
  &&&&&&& 1 &\\
  &&&&&&& 1 &\\
  &&&&&& 1 &.& 1\\
  &&&&& 1 &.& 1 &.& 1\\
  &&&&& 1 &.& 3 &.& 1\\
  &&&& 1 &.& 3 &.& 3 &.& 1\\
  &&& 1 &.& 3 &.& 5 &.& 3 &.& 1\\
  &&& 1 &.& 4 &.& 11 &.& 4 &.& 1\\
  && 1 &.& 5 &.& 11 &.& 11 &.& 5 &.& 1\\
  & 1 &.& 6 &.& 11 &.& 19 &.& 11 &.& 6 &.& 1\\
  & 1 &.& 7 &.& 16 &.& 41 &.& 16 &.& 7 &.& 1\\
   1 &.& 8 &.& 22 &.& 41 &.& 41 &.& 22 &.& 8 &.& 1\\
\end{matrix}
$$

By design:

- The row sums are the Fibonacci numbers $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, \ldots$.
- Each row looks like the Betti numbers of a projective algebraic variety.
- It is an analogue of Pascal's triangle, but for Fibonacci numbers.
- The numbers in each row count paths (see below).

I already know, but have not yet tried to prove:

- Most of the numbers are on or beneath the diagonal $1, 3, 11, 41, 155, 591,2267, 8735 \ldots$ of [OEIS:A136431](https://oeis.org/A136431), which is the recursive partial sums of Fibonacci numbers (aka hyperfibonacci).
- The numbers $1, 5, 19, 73, 281, 1085, 4201 \ldots$ are the diagonal of [OEIS:137176](https://oeis.org/A137176), which is the recursive partial sums of the Lucas numbers (aka hyperlucas).

The path counting is via steps going down one or two levels.

- If we go down one level we go straight down, or straight down and then out one column.
- If we go down two levels we usually go straight down, or straight and then in one column.
- It we go down two levels we usually go straight down, or straight down and in one step.

There are special down-two-levels rules for the middle five columns. Consider for example the last three rows of the table above.

- In the $1, 6$ row we have $4 + 11 + 4 = 19$ from the $1, 4$ row. This is a special case. And $19$ is a diagonal hyperlucas number.
- In $1, 7$ row we have $11 + 11 + 19 = 41$ (which is a hyperfibonacci number). This is NOT a special case. And $41$ is a diagonal hyperfibonacci number.
- In the $1, 8$ row the number $41$ appears twice. Once from the $41$ in the previous row. Once from $11 + 19 + 11$ from the $1, 6$ row. This is a special case.

URLs for the arxiv and for OEIS will be added as available. The arxiv should be available tomorrow (21 June).

Richard Stanley in [arxiv.org/abs/2101.02131](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02131) says that Doron Zeilberger asked:

> what happens when $2^n$ is replaced by some other function satisfying
> a linear recurrence with constant coefficients, such as the Fibonacci
> numbers

This is precisely the question I asked myself, but with $2^n$ and Pascal's triangle as the starting point. I sought a similar decomposition of the Fibonacci numbers.

Here are some specific questions (and I'd welcome more):

1. Is there a family of algebraic varieties with Betti numbers as given by this Fibonacci triangle?
2. The numbers $1, 5, 19$ in the central column continue as $73, 281, 1085, 4201$. These numbers also appear as a diagonal in [OEIS:A100240](https://oeis.org/A100240). Does this persist? Why the connection?
3. Does Richard Stanley's Fibonacci product [already referenced](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02131) have anything interesting in common with the Fibonacci triangle / wedding cake?

Comment: is there a question, or is this more like an announcement of a forthcoming paper?

Comment: Can you explain the rule for filling out the diagram? I'm not getting it.

Comment: @SamHopkins Each element contributes to an element in the next row, and also one in the row after that. Hence the row sums are the Fibonacci numbers.

We get 22 in the last row from 7 in the previous row and 11 in the one before that one. We get the first 41 in the last row from the 41 in the previous row. We get the second 41 from the 11, 19, 11 in the row before the previous row.

I hope this helps, and gives you enough to understand the remaining rules.

Comment: I still don't completely understand it, but anyways you might be interested in some arrays of numbers analogous to Pascal's triangle that have recently been studied by Richard Stanley in https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04647 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02131

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Your comment has prompted me to add some explicit questions. The arxiv paper adds 6 rows to the triangle shown here, and little else. There's a lot I don't understand about this triangle.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thank you so much for the link to Stanley's papers. I've added a reference to one of them, and also a question arising.

Comment: There isn't enough data here to tell, but I wonder if the diagonal sums correspond to a nice sequence.